# Changing multiple values in a list

Tags: python, replace, ascii

I'm writing an encryption code so I don't know exactly where each character I need to replace will be:
I have put a text file into a list and then the list into ascii, But i need to replace 32 with a space. I get this printed out so far but I need to replace 32 on the second list with " "

```
Original = ['S', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'w', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'l', 'a', ' ', 'M', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'a', ',', ' ', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'w', 'h', 'o', 's', 'e', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'd', 'o', ' ', 'n', 'o', 't', ' ', 'c', 'a', 'r', 'e', ' ', 't', 'o', ' ', 'r', 'e', 'm', 'e', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r', ',', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'g', 'e', 'n', 't', 'l', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'n', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'v', 'e', 'd', ' ', 'n', 'o', 't', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'a', 'g', 'o', ',', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'h', 'o', 's', 'e', ' ', 'w', 'h', 'o', ' ', 'h', 'a', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'l', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'd', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'i', 'e', 'n', 't', ' ', 's', 'h', 'i', 'e', 'l', 'd', ' ', 'o', 'n', ' ', 'a', ' ', 's', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'f', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'd', ' ', 'k', 'e', 'e', 'p', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 's', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'n', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'g', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'd', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'g', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'h', 'o', 'u', 'n', 'd', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'r', 'a', 'c', 'i', 'n', 'g', '.']


ASCII_conversion = [83, 111, 109, 101, 119, 104, 101, 114, 101, 32, 105, 110, 32, 108, 97, 32, 77, 97, 110, 99, 104, 97, 44, 32, 105, 110, 32, 97, 32, 112, 108, 97, 99, 101, 32, 119, 104, 111, 115, 101, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101, 32, 73, 32, 100, 111, 32, 110, 111, 116, 32, 99, 97, 114, 101, 32, 116, 111, 32, 114, 101, 109, 101, 109, 98, 101, 114, 44, 32, 97, 32, 103, 101, 110, 116, 108, 101, 109, 97, 110, 32, 108, 105, 118, 101, 100, 32, 110, 111, 116, 32, 108, 111, 110, 103, 32, 97, 103, 111, 44, 32, 111, 110, 101, 32, 111, 102, 32, 116, 104, 111, 115, 101, 32, 119, 104, 111, 32, 104, 97, 115, 32, 97, 32, 108, 97, 110, 99, 101, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 97, 110, 99, 105, 101, 110, 116, 32, 115, 104, 105, 101, 108, 100, 32, 111, 110, 32, 97, 32, 115, 104, 101, 108, 102, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 107, 101, 101, 112, 115, 32, 97, 32, 115, 107, 105, 110, 110, 121, 32, 110, 97, 103, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 97, 32, 103, 114, 101, 121, 104, 111, 117, 110, 100, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 114, 97, 99, 105, 110, 103, 46]
```

any help?

Comment: Add your code to that

Comment: You mean, you want a list with numbers and spaces, like `[..., 101, ' ', 105, ...]`?

Comment: Do you have sample code that you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new line of code after your current ASCII_conversion list:

```
ASCII_conversion = [x if x!=32 else " " for x in ASCII_conversion]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension with `TrueValue if condition else FalseValue` will do:

```
ASCII_conversion = [' ' if x == 32 else x for x in ASCII_conversion]
```

or combining the two operations

```
ASCII_conversion = [' ' if x == ' ' else ord(x) for x in Original]
```

Note #1: The above piece of code will produce a list containing both strings and integers. This might not be a good approach. Try to have all elements of a list of the same type. It helps reduce errors.

Note #2: Please work on on your variable naming convention. It sort of hurts readers' eyes.